# EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat amplify-codegen-temp\temp-console-log.txt

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am using AWS Amplify service. When I run command 'amplify push', I get the error "EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat *****/amplify-codegen-temp\temp-console-log.txt".

I am using a windows machine. Amplify CLI version is 11. npm version is 6.

I am getting error after seeing "Deployment state saved successfully". Can you please suggest.